# rails admin, s3, heroku, paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, rails-admin

I am at the final stage of deployment of my web app, and am trying to get S3 storage working. Basically, an admin user can log into the site, create a new "opportunity" using rails admin and then upload a picture using paperclip in rails admin. However when you go to save the new "opportunity" it doesn't work. I have been following this tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

And my project is on

https://github.com/jamescook106/do_one_thing

Please excuse my messy commits!

This is what my production.rb file has in:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... can you be more descriptive?  What happens?  Is there an error?  What is the error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There was an error in my S3 bucket settings causing access to be denied to it. Everything is all fixed now